# How to rename headers in many multi-fasta files with the name of a file?

Tags: bash, awk, bioinformatics, fasta

I have a directory with several hundred multi-FASTA files. These files are called with the name of the species or genus, such as:

```
Bubo_bubo.fasta
Poa_CC7849.fasta
Homo_sapiens.fasta
...
```

Inside each filem the headers are automatically generated by [Trinity assembler](https://github.com/trinityrnaseq/trinityrnaseq/wiki) and look similar to this example:

```
>c5_g1_i1 len=168 path=[174:0-148 24:148-168]
```

I would like to rename the headers in each of these files adding information about the species that it is coming from. So in other words, the header should contain in the beginning the name of the file. For example, if the header above comes from `Bubo_bubo.fasta` it should look like:

```
>Bubu_bubo_c5_g1_i1 len=168 path=[174:0-148 24:148-168]
```

So I want to write a loop that will take a file name and use this to add this information in each fasta header in this particular file and I want to do that for all the files in the directory.

Comment: does the len field in your header refer to the length of the file? in that case your header may be wrong when you change it.

Comment: @1010 it is a FASTA file, with the word _header_, the OP refers to a string which starts with `>` at the beginning of the line. The content of the string can be anything. There will be multiple headers per file. The lines following the header are generally a sequence of characters representing some biological data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do the trick for you:

```
awk '(FNR==1){f=FILENAME;sub(/\.[A-Za-z]*$/,"_",f)}
     /^>/{$0=">" f substr($0,2)}
     1' Bubo_bubo.fasta
```

This, however, will write everything to the screen, you might be interested in having new files instead. So you could use bash with a redirection for multiple files as:

```
for f in *.fasta; do
   awk '(FNR==1){f=FILENAME;sub(/\.[A-Za-z]*$/,"_",f)}
        /^>/{$0=">" f substr($0,2)}
        1' "$f" > "/path/to/new/location/$(basename $f)"
done
```

If you really want, you can do everything in awk itself, and this would be:

```
awk '(FNR==1){                             # When a new file is opened (first record)
        close(fout);                       # close previous output file
        fout=FILENAME
        sub(".*/", "", fout)               # get basename of file
        f=fout                             # set f to basename of file
        fout="path/to/new/location/" fout  # prepend output directory
        sub(/\.[A-Za-z]*$/,"_",f)          # remove extention from f
     }
     /^>/{$0=">" f substr($0,2)}           # if header found, update it
     {print > fout}                        # print to output file
    ' *.fasta
```

Comment: Hi @kvantour! Thank you for your help! And how could I indicate any fasta file? Just like that?  `awk '(FNR==1){f=FILENAME;sub(/\.[A-Za-z]*$/,"_",f)}
     /^>/{$0=">" f substr($0,2)}
     1' *.fasta`

Comment: @magda_wu yes. But this way it will output anything to the screen. Maybe mild update is in place. just a second.

Comment: @magda_wu I have added an update that will create files of the order "Bubo_bubo.fasta.new". Please test the script first before you run it over all your data. Maybe it does not do what you expect. However, I assume it does.

Comment: I have to admit that I have some troubles in understanding this command. Could you help me with it? Can I specify another directory to write the output by just replacing `{print > fout}` with `{print > ./anotherdir/fout}` ?

Comment: @magda_wu I have updated the answer a bit, I hope this explains it for you.

Comment: wow! thank you for y our update @kvantour! Your explanation really helped a lot!